# What's the simplest way to split 10 random numbers into two lists where the difference in the sum of the lists is as small as possible

Tags: list, sorting, sum, mirc

You get 10 numbers that you have to split into two lists where the sum of numbers in the lists have the smallest difference possible.

so let's say you get:

10 29 59 39 20 17 29 48 33 45

how would you sort this into two lists where the difference in the sum of the lists is as small as possible

so in this case, the answer (i think) would be:

59 48 29 17 10 = 163

45 39 33 29 20 = 166

I'm using mIRC script as the language but perl or C++ is just as good for me.

edit: actually there can be multiple answers such as in this scenario, it could also be:

59 48 29 20 10 = 166

45 39 33 29 17 = 163

to me, it doesn't matter so long as the end result is that the difference of the sum of the lists is as small as possible

edit 2: each list must contain 5 numbers.

Comment: I don't really know about the algorithm, but I can tell you this, don't try it on mIRC scripting, highly inefficient and hard to work with for actual programs.

Answer (score 0):

What you have listed is exactly the partition problem (for more details look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).
The point is that this is a NP-complete problem, therefore it does not exist a program able to solve any instance of this problem (i.e. with a bigger amount of numbers).

But if your problem is always with only ten numbers to divide into two lists of exactly five items each, then it becomes feasible, also to try naively all possible solutions, since they are only p^N, where p=2 is the number of partitions, and N=10 is the number of integers, thus only 2^10=1024 combinations, and each takes only O(N) to be verified (i.e. compute the difference).

Otherwise you can implement the greedy algorithm described in the Wikipedia page, it is simple to implement but there is no guarantee of optimality, in fact you can see this implementation in Java:

```
static void partition() {
    int[] set = {10, 29, 59, 39, 20, 17, 29, 48, 33, 45}; // array of data
    Arrays.sort(set); // sort data in descending order
    ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>(5); //first list
    ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>(5); //second list

    String stringA=new String(); //only to print result
    String stringB=new String(); //only to print result

    int sumA = 0; //sum of items in A
    int sumB = 0; //sum of items in B

    for (int i : set) {
        if (sumA <= sumB) {
            A.add(i); //add item to first list
            sumA+=i; //update sum of first list
            stringA+=" "+i;
        } else {
            B.add(i); //add item to second list
            sumB+=i; //update sum of second list
            stringB+=" "+i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("First list:" + stringA + " = " + sumA);
    System.out.println("Second list:"+ stringB+ " = " + sumB);
    System.out.println("Difference (first-second):" + (sumA-sumB));
}
```

It does not return a good result:

```
First list: 10 20 29 39 48 = 146
Second list: 17 29 33 45 59 = 183 
Difference (first-second):-37
```